# How to get value from parent parent scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-modal

On one page I'm doing something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="innerCommunicationTopic in data.InnerCommunicationTopics">
    <td>{{innerCommunicationTopic.Topic | Empty}}</td>
    <td>{{innerCommunicationTopic.WhenCreatedStr | Empty}}</td>
    <td>{{innerCommunicationTopic.WhenLastChangeStr | Empty}}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default margins" ng-click="showMsgs(innerCommunicationTopic.id)">Pokaż</button></td>
</tr>
```

Each **InnerCommunicationTopic** does have a List of InnerCommunicationMessage(s).

The button shows a modal where I want to present all InnerCommunicationMessage(s) in InnerCommunicationTopic. I just don't have a clue how to do this.

I call the modal here:

```
$scope.showMsgs = function (topicId) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: '/WWW/partials/createMsgModal.html'
    })
};
```

I've tried something like this in the modal:

```
<tr ng-repeat="innerCommunicationMessage in $parent.data.InnerCommunicationTopics[id].Messages">
    <td>{{innerCommunicationMessage.WhoCreated | Empty}}</td>
    <td>{{innerCommunicationMessage.WhenCreatedStr | Empty}}</td>
    <td>{{innerCommunicationMessage.Message | Empty}}</td>
</tr>
```

I know it's wrong, the *id* simply cannot work, but I don't really have an idea and I've already searched a lot for this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you want `InnerCommunicationTopics` with id which you are passing in `$scope.showMsgs = function (topicId) {` ? right?

Comment: Yes, each button has to lead to its own list of messages. Every `InnerCommunicationTopic` has a unique id value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind that specific id with scope and Pass your scope to modal like this:

```
$scope.showMsgs = function (topicId) {
    $scope.topicId = topicId;
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: '/WWW/partials/createMsgModal.html',
        scope: $scope
    })
};
```

Then in modal you can use `topicId`

```
<tr ng-repeat="innerCommunicationMessage in data.InnerCommunicationTopics[topicId].Messages">
    <td>{{innerCommunicationMessage.WhoCreated | Empty}}</td>
    <td>{{innerCommunicationMessage.WhenCreatedStr | Empty}}</td>
    <td>{{innerCommunicationMessage.Message | Empty}}</td>
</tr>
```

This way you do not have to use `$parent.data`, only `data` will work, because this modal has scope of parent.

Comment: I am glad that it helped.  :)

Answer (score 1):

A good and proper way to share some data between multiple controller is to use **Service**. In AngularJS, Services are **Singleton**, so you can easily share data.

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service(){

    var data;

    function set(value){
      data = value;
    }

    function get(){
      return data;
    }

    return {
      get: get,
      set: set
    };

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Service, $modal) {

  //Example of dataset
  $scope.data = [
    {
      name: 'toto',
      id: '1',
      list: [
        {
          message:'ok',
          id: '123'
        },
        {
          message: 'nop',
          id: '456'
        }
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'john',
      id: '2',
      list: [
        {
          message:'blabla',
          id: '123d'
        },
        {
          message: 'l,kdn',
          id: '94ss'
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  $scope.show = function(data){
    //Set your data into your Service
    Service.set(data);
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: true,
      templateUrl: 'templateModal.html',
      controller: function($scope){
        //Retrieve our data from your Service
        $scope.data = Service.get();
      }
    })

  }

}

angular
.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Template**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">List of {{data.name}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <ul ng-repeat="item in data.list">
    <li>Message : {{item.message}}</li>
    <li>id : {{item.id}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can pass your item to the `show` function in your html.

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">

    <ul ng-repeat="item in data">
      <li>{{item.name}}</li>
      <li>{{item.id}}</li>
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default margins" ng-click="show(item)">Show modal</button>
    </ul>

  </body>
```

You can see the [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/4fXh0eG1Dnj4EA53BEiS?p=preview)

Comment: I will look into it out of curiosity and to see if it works better, but _mudasser ajaz_ has already given a simple and working answer. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes to your `ng-repeater` where the `Modal` will be generated from and instead of passing the `id` when the button is clicked, pass in the content of `InnerCommunicationTopics[id].Messages` that way you can pass this data over to the modal.

**So something like this:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="innerCommunicationTopic in data.InnerCommunicationTopics">
    <td>{{innerCommunicationTopic.Topic | Empty}}</td>
    <td>{{innerCommunicationTopic.WhenCreatedStr | Empty}}</td>
    <td>{{innerCommunicationTopic.WhenLastChangeStr | Empty}}</td>
    <td>
     <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default margins" 
             ng-click="showMsgs(InnerCommunicationTopics[innerCommunicationTopic.id].Messages)">
      Pokaż
     </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Now on the Controller thats handling the button click, grab the data and pass it over to the modal like so:**

```
app.controller('MainWindowCtrl', function ($scope, $modal) {

    $scope.dataToDisplayInModal = {};

    $scope.showMsgs = function(data){

        $scope.dataToDisplayInModal = {
               topic: data[0],
               whenCreated: data[1],
               whenLastChanged: data[2]
        };

        //Create your Modal and inside resolve we pass in the Data we crafted above.
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: '../Scripts/Templates/WorkOrderModalTemplate.html',
                    controller: 'EditWorkOrderModalCtrl',
                    windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false,
                    resolve: {
                        dataToDisplayInModal: function () {
                            return $scope.dataToDisplayInModal;
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**In your Modal's controller handle the incoming data**

```
app.controller('EditWorkOrderModalCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, dataToDisplayInModal) {

    //Create local instance of the Data to use in this context
    $scope.listOfMessages = dataToDisplayInModal;
});
```

**In your Modal's template you can then have the following.**

```
<tr ng-repeat="message in listOfMessages">
    <td>{{message.topic | Empty}}</td>
    <td>{{message.whenCreate | Empty}}</td>
    <td>{{message.whenLastChanged | Empty}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I still don't get it. How do I get the data from data.InnerCommunicationTopic?

Comment: Rewrote my answer, take a look. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll try it, but I do have a working solution now, thank you anyway!